# Compare and Contrast Change Data Capture and Database Change Notification

Tags: oracle, change-data-capture

Oracle has two seemingly competing technologies. CDC and DCN.

What are the strengths of each?

When would you use one and not the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you would use DCN to notify a client application that the client application needs to clear/ update the application's cache.  You would use CDC for ETL processing.

DCN would generally be preferable when you have an OLTP application that needs to be notified immediately about data changes in the database.  Since the goal here is to minimize the number of network round-trips and the number of database hits, you'd generally want the application to use DCN for queries which either are mostly static.  If a large fraction of the query is changing regularly, you may be better off just refreshing the application's cache on a set frequency rather than running queries constantly to get the changed data (DCN does not contain the changed data, just the ROWID of the row(s) that changed).  If the application goes down, I believe DCN allows changes to be lost.

CDC would generally be preferable when you have a DSS application that needs to periodically pull over all the data that changed in a number of tables.  CDC can guarantee that the subscriber has received every change to the underlying table(s) which can be important if you are trying to replicate changes to a different database .  CDC allows the subscriber to pull the changes at its convenience rather than trying to notify the subscriber that there are changes, so you'd definitely want CDC if you wanted the subscriber to process new data every hour or every day rather than in near real time. *(note: DCN also has a guaranteed delivery mode, see comments below. --Mark Harrison)*

Comment: DCN can be put in a mode to guarantee delivery. Disk vs memory basically.

Answer (score 1):

CDC seems to be much more complex to set up than DCN.

I mean to setup DCN I wrap a select in a start and end DCN block and then write a procedure to be called with a collect of changes. That's it.

CDC requires publishers and subscribers and anyways, seems like more work.